# RenderTargetBitmap::RenderAsync ignores the size arguments?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

The documentation says "Specifies the target width at which to render" / "Specifies the target height at which to render".

However, the resulting RenderTargetBitmap completely ignores that arguments.
E.g. in the 1080p WP8.1 simulator it renders as 1920x1080, even if the arguments are 853x480.

Is there a way to make the RenderTargetBitmap::RenderAsync method to work [as advertised](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn298557.aspx)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not ignore them. It just automatically multiplies them by [DisplayInformation.RawPixelsPerViewPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation.rawpixelsperviewpixel.aspx).

I don't think this can be avoided at the moment. But you can always calculate what arguments you need to pass to get the result that you want.